# Something keeps rewriting my Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, bundler

Working on a shared project, I often find that my `Gemfile.lock` gets out of sync with the repository, producing error messages like:

```
$ git pull
Updating 1911275..8c5d26f
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Gemfile.lock
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

When I try to `git stash` the change, it doesn't work:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on development: 1911275 Merge branch 'development' of https://github.com/mygroup/myrepo into development
HEAD is now at 1911275 Merge branch 'development' of https://github.com/mygroup/myrepo into development
$ git status
On branch development
Your branch is behind 'origin/development' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Gemfile.lock

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I `stash` and `status` quickly enough, I can see that the change is getting stashed:

```
$ git stash && git status
Saved working directory and index state WIP on development: 1911275 Merge branch 'development' of https://github.com/mygroup/myrepo into development
HEAD is now at 1911275 Merge branch 'development' of https://github.com/mygroup/myrepo into development
On branch development
Your branch is behind 'origin/development' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But another `status` shows that `Gemfile.lock` has come back:

```
$ git status
On branch development
Your branch is behind 'origin/development' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Gemfile.lock

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Unfortunately the same trick doesn't work with `git stash && git pull`; `pull` is too slow, and the lockfile reappears before the pull can succeed.

I thought it might be my IDE re-bundling in the background, but it happens whether or not the IDE is running. I can't find any running bundler processes, gem processes, or indeed any obvious Ruby processes of any kind.

Who or what is regenerating my file?

Comment: Can you just git ignore your lock file? I know this does not answer the question but could resolve the issue

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: tell us what is changing in the lock file. there lies the clue.

Comment: @BradWerth macOS (El Capitan).

Comment: @emaillenin I don't think so. It's just some random gem versions, different ones each time.

Comment: It would help if you can identify what changes have been made, perhaps via `git diff` or by looking between the `>>>` sections identifying a conflict. Newer versions of Bundler put in a version stamp, and out of sync versions can cause version control noise.

Comment: @engineersmnky For reproducibility, we want the application Gemfile.lock in version control. (Cf. [this discussion](http://doc.crates.io/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries) around Cargo.lock, which plays a similar role in the Rust world.)

Comment: @tadman it's usually one line, e.g. `- jquery-turbolinks (~> 2.1.0) / + jquery-turbolinks` or `+ unf_ext (0.0.7.3) / + unf_ext (0.0.7.2)`. Whatever's causing the file to be regenerated has nothing to do with the content as such; it's just rerunning `bundle install` in a slightly different environment from the previousi checkin (or doing something else that has the same effect).

Comment: @DavidMoles I understand just a thought I mean obviously you could always lock gem versions explicitly or at least major.minor version in the Gemfile itself

Comment: Looks like some kind of oddball platform issue. JRuby vs. MRI Ruby? Windows vs. Linux?

Comment: @tadman Nope, the whole team is on MRI and macOS, though some use rvm and some use rbenv. I think the differences are mostly a matter of timing (e.g. a new version of some gem being released in between different developers' runs of `bundle install`.)

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard macOS. see above comments.

Comment: @MattSchuchard (Also, no offense meant, but a comment consisting of nothing but a `cyberciti.biz` URL looks sketchy AF—I was this close to flagging as spam without clicking.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the culprit, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29134747/27358) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790448/27358) concurs): [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring). There were half a dozen rogue `spring` processes on my machine, and any or all of them must have been regenerating the file. Killing those processes solved the problem, and so far adding `export DISABLE_SPRING=1` to my `.bash_profile` seems to have kept it from recurring.

(`spring stop` might have worked too. I don't know whether it stops all Spring processes or just one of them, though.)

Comment: Thanks! `spring stop` did the trick for me.

Comment: THanks a lot buddy. Ran into the same proble. U r a lifesaver

Comment: `killall -9 ruby` ftw, so tired of spring and its meddling.

Comment: Killing VSCode did the trick for me.

Comment: @Magsafe same here, did you found the reason?